# Does the ANSI SQL Standard allow filters or parameters in JOIN conditions?

Tags: mysql, join, syntax, sql-standard

Does the ANSI Standard find the following SQL sinppet syntactically correct?  I am interested specifically in the last line:

```
SELECT name, dept_name
FROM employee JOIN department
     ON employee.dept_id = department.dept_id
     JOIN payroll ON payroll_type = 1;
```

Comment: But that is effectively a "cross join", since you have not spelled out how `payroll` relates to any of the other tables.

Comment: That is part of the problem as it turns out - no columns are retrieved from this table and removing the filter does not change the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is syntactically correct.

The `ON` clause can be any boolean expression - i.e. as long as it results in a boolean value (`TRUE`, `FALSE`, `UNKNOWN`).

---

Note that you have 3 tables that are visible in that `ON` clause: `employee`, `department` and `payroll`. You'll get an error if `payroll_type` is a column in more than one of them.